# Change query into mysql?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, postgresql

I have query like this

```
$where = $where." CAST({$field} AS TEXT) = '{$value_i}' AND ";

$a[] = "CAST({$field} AS TEXT) ~* '{$value_i}'";
```

if I excecute on postgres it's ok nevermind and if i excecute on mysql error in CAST $field=text, how to change into query on mysql?

thanks b4.

Comment: Which column tyoe is $field? MySQL does a lot of conversions automatically while PostgreSQL does not.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$where = $where." CAST({$field} AS CHAR) = '{$value_i}' AND ";

$a[] = "CAST({$field} AS CHAR) RLIKE '{$value_i}'";
```

[The documentation lists all operators and function MySQL 5.6 knows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/func-op-summary-ref.html). Pay especially attention that [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) may behave slightly different than [`~*`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP); it is however by default case-insensitive.

Wether or not you need to use `CAST` explicitly depends on a few things. [This articel explains which types are automatically converted and when](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following are the only valid `TYPE` you can `CAST` as in MySql.

- BINARY[(N)]
- CHAR[(N)]
- DATE
- DATETIME
- DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
- SIGNED [INTEGER]
- TIME
- UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

*Reference [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) for more information.*

As you can see, `TEXT` is not one of them. You probably want `CHAR`.